# MYSQL user privilege to execute UPDATE scripts?

Tags: mysql

I'm doing a shell script that runs a single UPDATE instruction to a table. As i do not want to use my root user decided to make a user just for this case. I let checked just the UPDATE privilege but when trying to run the script i get an "access denied". I wonder if the user needs more privileges.

[image]

Here is the error:
mysql -u user -ppass Database -e "UPDATE tickets SET email = LOWER(email);"

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using pass                  word: YES)

Comment: Not that I'm experienced with MySQL, but an `UPDATE` needs to lock the table - so I'd grant them **LOCK TABLES** too.

Answer (score 0):

> The SELECT privilege is also needed for other statements that read
>   column values. For example, SELECT is needed for columns referenced on
>   the right hand side of col_name=expr assignment in UPDATE statements
>   or for columns named in the WHERE clause of DELETE or UPDATE
>   statements.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html